# How to use 'this' in a javascript function in a php foreach and to make it work separately?

Tags: javascript, php

I would like to trigger the appearance of a text after pressing a button for each user individually,The objective is that if you press the button of a specific user, the text will appear only for this one and not for the others. Unfortunately my code does not work. When I click on the button the text appears for all users. How can I do it?

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
  <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
          <div style="padding-top: 90px; padding-left: 30px;">
              <div class="user_style2">
                  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">

                          <p>install_id</p>
                          <p>branch_id</p>
                      </div>
                      <button onclick="hiddenButton(this)">Try it</button>

                      <div class="DIV" name="DIV">
                          This is my DIV element.
                      </div>
                     
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

<?php
                }
                // End the foreach loop 
           ?>

<script>
  function hiddenButton(this) {
      var x = document.getElementsByClassName("DIV");
      
      for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
          if (x[i].style.display === "none") {
              x[i].style.display = "block";
          } else {
              x[i].style.display = "none";
          }
  }
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: The problem is that every class name of every user is called `DIV`. You need to make it unique.

Comment: how can I make the class unique?

Comment: Making a `className` unique for every element would make no sense. It is `ID` attributes that **must** be unique but `className` attributes serve the purpose primarily of styling elements - to make them unique would be an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly straightforward - assign a single delegated event handler to a common ancestor ( here simply the document itself ) and use the `event` and specifically the `event.target` to identify which button invoked the click event. From that you can query the DOM using `querySelector` ( or by other means if required such as sibling selectors )

The question title refers to using `this` within your function but you have that supplied as the argument where one might expect `event` - and you should be able to access the `target` property in the same manner as in the code here.

```js
document.addEventListener('click',e=>{
  if( e.target.tagName=='BUTTON' ){
    let div=e.target.parentNode.querySelector('div.DIV');
      div.style.display=div.style.display=='block' ? 'none' : 'block'
  }
})
```

```css
.DIV{
  display:none
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <div style="padding-top: 90px; padding-left: 30px;">
        <div class="user_style2">
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">

              <p>install_id</p>
              <p>branch_id</p>
            </div>
            <button>Try it</button>
            <div class="DIV" name="DIV">
              This is my DIV element.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <div style="padding-top: 90px; padding-left: 30px;">
        <div class="user_style2">
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">

              <p>install_id</p>
              <p>branch_id</p>
            </div>
            <button>Try it</button>
            <div class="DIV" name="DIV">
              This is my DIV element.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <div style="padding-top: 90px; padding-left: 30px;">
        <div class="user_style2">
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">

              <p>install_id</p>
              <p>branch_id</p>
            </div>
            <button>Try it</button>
            <div class="DIV" name="DIV">
              This is my DIV element.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The meaning of `this` varies depending upon how it is used but using it like this `function hiddenButton(this){}` is not correct. Consider these simple examples of referring to `this` within a function / event handler.

```js
document.getElementById('apple').addEventListener('click',function(e){
  console.info(`
    function(e){} /* conventional */
    this:%s
    this.id:%s
    e.target:%s
    e.target.id:%s`,
    this,
    this.id,
    e.target,
    e.target.id
  );
});

document.getElementById('banana').addEventListener('click',e=>{
  console.info(`
    (e)={}/* arrow */
    this:%s
    this.id:%s
    e.target:%s
    e.target.id:%s`,
    this,
    this.id,
    e.target,
    e.target.id
  );
});

function hiddenButton(that){
  console.info(`
    function(this){} /* inline */
    this:%s
    that:%s
    this.id:%s
    that.id:%s`,
    this,
    that,
    this.id,
    that.id
  );
}
```

```css
.fruit div{
  padding:0.5rem;
  width:100px;
  margin:0.5rem;
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:center;
  border:2px solid black;
  border-radius:0.5rem;
}
.fruit div:after{
  content:attr(id)
}

#apple{
  background:green;
  color:white;
}
#banana{
  background:yellow
}
#plum{
  background:purple;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class='fruit'>
  <div id='apple'></div>
  <div id='banana'></div>
  <div id='plum' onclick='hiddenButton(this)'></div>
</div>
```